# Why is the range of $\sqrt{9-x^2}$ actually $[0,3]$ instead of $[-3,3]$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

Why is the range of $y=\sqrt{9-x^2}$ $[0,3]$ instead of $[-3,3]$? Solving it algebraically, it is my understanding that the answer would be the second one. But that is apparently not the right answer. Could someone explain to me why this is? Thanks.

O shoot I'm sorry. thought the domain of the function was [0,3].

Comment: See:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1547553/why-does-the-domain-and-range-of-sqrt-x-contain-only-positive-real-numbers

Comment: because $\sqrt y\ge0$

Comment: Sorry, got confused and thought it was the domain. Nevermind. Thanks for the help though

Comment: This exact same question has been asked a couple of times on here. See references.

Comment: how do you delete a question?

Answer (score 0):

What real value can you pick so that $\sqrt{9-x^2} = -1$? After all, on the real numbers, $\sqrt{\cdot}$ maps non-negative reals into non-negative reals...

Answer (score 0):

You actually found the domain of the function, $x\in [-3, 3]$. With this, can you find the range?